# Why does my Dijkstra's return the incorrect result?

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm doing my first Dijkstra's algorithm problem from LeetCode and I'm struggling to understand why it's failing. I'm stuck, and I don't want to look at other implementations without understanding what's wrong with mine.

```
import heapq
from collections import defaultdict

def network_delay_time(times, n, source):
    """
    A function which takes in a list of edges representing a graph of network nodes
    and the time to travel between the nodes, the number of nodes in the network
    graph, and a source node. 

    The function returns the minimum amount of time to travel to all of the nodes in
    the graph from the source node.

    Parameters:
    times (List[List[int]]): List of edges representing the time to travel between nodes in the graph.
            times[i] = (uᵢ, vᵢ, wᵢ) --> u = start node, v = target node, w = edge weight between source & target

    n (int): The total number of nodes in the network graph

    source (int): The source node from which to travel the network

    Returns:
    Int: The minimum amount of time to travel to all of the nodes in the graph.
    """
    if not times:
        return None
    
    adj_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for start_node, target_node, edge_weight in times:
        adj_dict[start_node].append((target_node, edge_weight))

    visited = set()
    queue = [(source, 0)]
    distances_dict = {}

    for key in range(1,n+1):
        distances_dict[key] = float('inf')
    distances_dict[source] = 0

    while queue:
        current_node, edge_weight = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if current_node in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(current_node)

        for neighbor in adj_dict[current_node]:
            if neighbor[0] not in visited:
                distance = neighbor[1] + distances_dict[current_node]
                if distance < distances_dict[neighbor[1]]:
                    distances_dict[neighbor[1]] = distance
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (neighbor, distance))
                    print(visited)
            

    if len(visited) < n:
        print(visited)
        return -1
    else:   
        return max(distances_dict.values())

print(network_delay_time([[2,1,1], [2,3,1], [3,4,1]], 4, 2))
```

It should return 2 for this specific one but I keep getting -1. I created the dict in comments to help me debug. I've tried printing out the values of everything. I just don't see what's wrong but I think the issue is in the conditional of my for loop.

```
# {
#     1: None
#     2: (1,1), (3,1)
#     3: (4,1)
#     4: None
# }
```

Comment: Your heap is sorting by node number, rather than distance.

Comment: @Blckknght How do I fix that, then, because I thought it should sort by node to make sure each one gets visited? If you don't mind my asking!

Comment: "How do I fix that, then, because I thought it should sort by node" What part of your code do you think does the sorting? Do you understand how to explain what to sort by? Do you understand how to compute the relevant distances?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: @user22248976 Expandindg on Blckknght's comment: tuples comparison semantics is, we compare first elements, if they're equal we compare second, etc. If tuple is (node_id, distance), then node id is compared first, not the distance. Just swap the two

Comment: @KarlKnechtel When I initially asked the question, I thought I had narrowed down the issue to being the condition in my for loop because when I was printing things outs to see what was going on, everything (as far as I know) looked fine until that point but after reading blckknght's comment, it looks like that I was wrong about that. :(  As I said, this is my first time solving a problem like this, so it's likely I misunderstood which part is doing the sorting. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Marat I see now. I had to go over it again. Thank you for the tuple explanation! I think what happened was I initially had them in a different order, and confused myself after switching them for reading clarity.